# lucene 4.x user-defined Filter, the DocsEnum in getDocIdSet(....) returns null and fail to work

Tags: lucene

I make use of lucene 4.0 to build my search engine. I need to define a Filter when searching. The filter code like this will work fine:

```
public DocIdSet getDocIdSet(AtomicReaderContext context, Bits acceptDocs)
        throws IOException {
            String[] target_real_names = {"eMule"};
    OpenBitSet obs = new OpenBitSet(context.reader().maxDoc());
    for(String target_real_name : target_real_names){
        TermQuery query=new TermQuery(new Term(Fields.PROJECT_REAL_NAME,target_real_name)); 
        IndexSearcher indexSearcher=new IndexSearcher(context.reader());  
        TopDocs docs=indexSearcher.search(query,context.reader().maxDoc());  
        ScoreDoc[] scoreDocs=docs.scoreDocs;  
        if (scoreDocs.length==1) {  
            obs.set(scoreDocs[0].doc);  
        }  
    }
    return obs;
}
```

but the code like this fail to work:

```
public DocIdSet getDocIdSet(AtomicReaderContext context, Bits acceptDocs)
        throws IOException {
    OpenBitSet obs = new OpenBitSet(context.reader().maxDoc());
            String[] target_real_names = {"eMule"};
    for(String target_real_name : target_real_names){
        DocsEnum de = context.reader().termDocsEnum(new Term(Fields.PROJECT_REAL_NAME, target_real_name));
        if(de.nextDoc()!= -1){
            obs.set((long)de.docID());
        }
    }
    return obs;
}
```

In this piece of code, the de will be null, I don't know why. Any one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the javadoc of termDocsEnum() --> This will return null if either the field or term does not exist.

This means that it's totally normal that de is null when your term `target_real_name` does not exist.

Comment: At first I think that the term not exist in the field. Then I choose the "eMule" which in actual exist in the filed. When using lucene3.0 with  "termDocs" it works fine

Comment: As far as I know, termDocs method in lucene 3 never return null, even when your term doesn't exist. The term "eMule" may exist in some segments (AtomicReaders) but it may not exist in others. When you use the filter on search, in will be called for multiple times, once for each AtomicReader.

Comment: Then if "eMule" exist in AtomicReaders, why it returns null? How to solve this problem?

Comment: It only exist in some AtomicReaders and in other AtomicReaders, it does not. Just change `if(de.nextDoc()!= -1){obs.set((long)de.docID());` to `if(de!=null){obs.set((long)de.nextDoc());`.